# Shell. How to exit the current script and go back to parent script that calls it?

Tags: shell

For example, `A.sh` calls `B.sh` inside the source code. The call is as the following in `A.sh`

```
#Inside A.sh    
. ./B.sh
```

Now, some `if..else` statement happened in `B.sh` and decided to stop executing `B.sh`. How to make it go back to `A.sh` and keep executing the rest of the codes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably noticed that if you call `exit` from a file that's being sourced, you exit the entire shell, not just that file.

Instead, you can use `return`, which (in addition to returning from a function) will return control to the command following the `.` command.

Note that it is an error to `return` from a script that is being *executed*, rather than sourced, so make sure that you only use `return` outside of a function in a file that will be sourced.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` basically means run this file in the current shell. That means that any `exit` or similar will exit the current (A) shell.

You need to make sure B is done in a different shell.

I haven't tested it, but `( . ./B.sh )` might work...

As others have stated, you can simplify event more: `./B.sh` is also likely to work.

Comment: `.` is usually used because you _need_ to run the script in the same shell, so this is not likely to be a useful answer. The duplicate question I linked to has an answer that works.

Answer (score -1):

foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hi"
./bar.sh
echo "done"
```

bar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "bar here!"
[[ "1" == "1" ]] && exit 0
echo "oh no!"
```

Run foo.sh:

```
$ ./foo.sh
hi
bar here!
done
```

Comment: You're ignoring the requirement that `B.sh` is being sourced, not executed as a script. There are legitimate and necessary reasons for doing so; executing as a script so that you can use `exit` may not be possible.

Comment: @chepner Ah, good call. Thanks for the correction.